# Cannot move local file to mounted s3 drive? PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I am using s3fs to mount an amazon s3 drive to my filesystem. When I use PHP's rename() function to move a local file to the mounted drive nothing happens. Is rename() okay to use for this?

```
$tempfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp.png';
rename($tempfile,'/mnt/test.png');
```

Above code is not working for me. The drive appears to be mounted as I can see its files.

It turns out it was a permission problem - I fixed it with the "allow_other" option for s3fs, but now I am getting this php error while using rename():

```
failed to open stream: Input/output error
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't rename files across filesystems in general. You'll have to copy the file, then delete the original. (The issue doesn't arise with `mv` because it automatically detects the situation and does the whole copy/delete thing.)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, but I was using Java. Since it s3fs emulates a filesystem it's impossible to copy the file from one fs to the other.

I had to write two copies of the file; one directly to local fs and then one to the emulated drive.

Comment: The problem actually isn't specific to s3fs.

Answer (score 0):

Found this gem [here](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) - and that solved my **"Input/output error"** when trying to upload files to my mounted S3 bucket:

> Recently, I ran into the infamous **"Input/output error"** on a new install of r188. The S3 bucket was fine, and everything else correct, but still was not working.
>
> It took quite a while to discover that my problem had to do with the "**+**" character that was part of the secretAccessKey.
>
> I created a new access key, and substituted that info into the */etc/passwd-s3fs* file and all started working.